# How can I update a parent checkbox by whether it's children are checked or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

My code works fine in case I check the main check box all the child check boxes get selected too but when I click the child first the parent check box does not get checked.
Here is my asp.net webforms code

```
<table id="dtPage" class="table  table-striped table-hover ">
  <thead>
    <tr>                                 
      <th><asp:CheckBox ID="chkActiveUsers" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />Associate</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
       <tr>
         <td>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkUserStatus" CssClass="enable-user" runat="server" />

         </td>
       </tr>
```

and here is my JavaScript:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {


        $('#chkActiveUsers').click(function () {

            $(".enable-user input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
        });
    });
```

**My Question is:** How can I make it work vice versa i.e. when child is check parent should get checked too and when no child is checked parent should get unchecked too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply write an event handler for your child checkboxes and compare the length of checked and total existing checkboxes like this:-

```
$('input[name$="chkUserStatus"]').click(function () {
   if ($('input[name$="chkUserStatus"]').length == $('input[name$="chkUserStatus"]:checked').length) 
         $('#chkActiveUsers').prop('checked', true);
   else 
         $('#chkActiveUsers').prop('checked', false);
});
```

**Update:**

If you want that if only the last child checkbox is unchecked only then the paremt should be unchecked then you can do it like this:-

```
$('input[name$="chkUserStatus"]').click(function () {
   if ($('input[name$="chkUserStatus"]:checked').length != 0) 
         $('#chkActiveUsers').prop('checked', true);
   else 
         $('#chkActiveUsers').prop('checked', false);
});
```

Comment: nothing happened even what I achieved before that ended with this. no error shown in the console either

Comment: @user3515453 - What? Have you tried the exact code? Its working perfectly fine for me. In your existing code what is `chkActive` BTW?

Comment: That is some other part of some other check box nothing to do with this one. only second part  $('#chkActiveUsers').click(function () {
is that matters

Comment: @user3515453 - Okay got it. I guess you have done something wrong while trying this code that is the reason the else block is executing and disabling the parent checkbox. Can you place console.log in `if` and `else` blocks and see if it is displaying correct values?

Comment: I put a debugger their nothing appears to happen when child is called. it does not even go their

Comment: @user3515453 - Don't just rely on debugger, please put an alert or console log. Can you check how is the `name` attribute of your child checkbox `chkUserStatus` is rendered in browser?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99800/discussion-between-rahul-singh-and-user3515453).

Comment: let me first find that how can I do that :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some way of grouping the children and parents so you can find the parent checkbox relative to the child checkbox. Once you've achieved that you can just do checks against the checkboxes to see if you need to do anything.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'input.child', function() {
  var parent = $(this).closest('.typeContainer').find('input.parent'),
    parentChecked = parent.is(':checked');
  if ($(this).is(':checked') && !parentChecked) { // If the child is checked but the parent is not
    parent.prop('checked', true);
  } else if (!$(this).is(':checked') && parentChecked) { // Else if the child is not checked and the parent is
    var doUncheck = true;
    $(this).closest('ul').find('input.child').not(this).each(function() { // Loop through all the sibling children checkboxes
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) { // If one of them is checked
        doUncheck = false; // Don't uncheck the parent
        return; // Exit loop because required parameters are complete
      }
    });
    if (doUncheck) {
      parent.prop('checked', false);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="typeContainer">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" class="parent" />Parent 1
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" class="child" />Child 1.1
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" class="child" />Child 1.2
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" class="child" />Child 1.3
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" class="child" />Child 1.4
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<ul class="typeContainer">
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" class="parent" />Parent 2
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" class="child" />Child 2.1
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" class="child" />Child 2.2
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" class="child" />Child 2.3
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" class="child" />Child 2.4
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No sir no Ul Li stuff, if I can achieve what I've already done why not this one too

Comment: @user3515453 UL and LI's are just used for a simple parent/child relationship demonstration. Just replace the that with whatever matches in your tabular style.

Comment: can not do that its an ASP.NET repeater and other stupid stuff related to that used can NOT do that sir